# How to check if a Type is custom Class

Tags: c#

I'm trying fill a list of object from data table using the following method

```
public static List<T> toList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var obj = new T();
            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                Type targetType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
                if (table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        object value = row[prop.Name];
                        if (value != null)
                        {
                            if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
                                {
                                    value = null;
                                }
                            }
                            if (targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
                            {
                                targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
                            }

                            value = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've the following models

```
public class A
{
    public string str1 {get;set;}
    public int int1 {get;set;}
    public DateTime dateTime1 {get;set;}
}
public class B
{
    public string str2 {get;set;}
    public int int2 {get;set;}
    public DateTime dateTime2 {get;set;}
    public A vara {get;set;}
}
```

My Data table looks like this

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|   str1    |   str2    |   int1    |   int2    |   dateTime1   |   dateTime2   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|   "abc"   |   "def"   |   1       |   2       |   NULL        |   NULL        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

All this works fine If I use

```
List<B> list = dataTable.toList<B>();
```

But I also want to set the value of vara in each element of list.

**How can I check that if a Type is custom defined type?**
I can not use Type.IsClass because it is true for string too.
If I can detect that a property is of Custom Class Type then I can fill that's value using the same method.
I hope that I've explained it well.

Comment: Can you define *precisely* what you mean by "custom defined type"? For example, would you include (say) a type from a third-party library such as Json.NET as "custom defined"?

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out which object has a “custom type”, whatever that is, you should ensure that the code either works on every type, or prevents invalid types from being used (via the use of interfaces).

Comment: When I say **Custom Defined Type** it means that a class created by me, like class A and class B. Actually Class B has four properties with four different Types. Types like string, int and DateTime are defined by default. But class A is defined by me. I want to detect that in properties of class B, which property has Type defined by me

Comment: If you want to check for your own types, would it help if  you inspect the namespace of that type?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It can help but that would not be a generic solution.

Comment: What if the class if from a reference you have. How do you know it's yours or not? Like File.Configuration Something trivial enought to be either 3rd party lib or .net or yours. Are we allowed to modify the custom class to make them easier to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able create a following generic solution

```
public static List<T> toList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        var list = table.toList(typeof(T));
        var newLIst = list.Cast<T>().ToList();
        return newLIst;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static List<object> toList(this DataTable table, Type type)
{
    try
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var obj = row.toObject(type);
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static object toObject(this DataRow row, Type type, string sourcePropName = "")
{
    try
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(prop.Name);
            Type targetType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            string propName = prop.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePropName))
            {
                propName = sourcePropName + "__" + propName;
                if (!row.Table.Columns.Contains(propName))
                {
                    propName = prop.Name;
                }
            }
            if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(propName))
            {
                try
                {
                    object value = row[propName];
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
                            {
                                value = null;
                            }
                        }
                        targetType = targetType.handleNullableType();
                        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            if (targetType.IsClass && targetType != typeof(string))
            {
                if (targetType.IsGenericList())
                {
                    Type ltype = targetType.GetProperty("Item").PropertyType;
                    object value = row.toObject(ltype, propName);
                    if (value == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var valList = new List<object> { value }.ConvertList(targetType);
                    try
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, valList);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error(ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    object value = row.toObject(targetType, propName);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value);
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    catch 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static object ConvertList(this List<object> value, Type type)
{
    IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var item in value)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

In order to fill all properties of class B including vara property, I must prefix the names of columns that belong to vara properties and added splitter **___**

Therefore, the about table should be as follows

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
|   vara__str1    |   str2    |   vara__int1    |   int2    |   vara__dateTime1   |   dateTime2   |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
|   "abc"         |   "def"   |   1             |   2       |   NULL              |   NULL        |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------+
```